# Cross domain error handling using Jquery for ContentWindow errors

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

I have an iframe and with a back button in the parent window. I want the back button to work exactly as the browser history button. The issue is with cross domain. If I click open a different domain page, then my code throws error.

***Here is my code***

```
## Initialization code ##
 window.iFrameChanges = -1; //will get incremented to 0 on first page load


## iframe on load event ##
function iframeOnLoad() {
 window.iFrameChanges+=1;
}

## Back button - click event ##
if(window.iFrameChanges > 1) { 
 document.getElementById("show-file").contentWindow.history.go(-1); 
}else {
 window.iFrameChanges = -1;
}
```

***Error***

> Error: Permission denied to access property 'history'
>   document.getElementById("show-file").contentWindow.history.go(-1);

Am not looking for a exact solution for this as I am aware of the cross domain issues (on the other hand if there is any sol. pls let me know). I just want to **handle these errors properly using jQuery, so as to have a better end user experience.**

**Kindly advice**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding a try catch around the code

```
try {
 document.getElementById("show-file").contentWindow.history.go(-1); 
 window.iFrameChanges -= 1;
}
catch(err) {
window.iFrameChanges = -1;

    ## code to show message to user (if required) ##            
}
```